# JAR file: digital signature

Tags: manifest, signature, jar

If a JAR file is digitally signed, does the signature become part of the manifest file?

Answer (score 5):

Almost. Actually it is not the JAR file which is signed, but its contents.

Technically, the individual files in the JAR archive which are to be signed are hashed with a suitable hash function (e.g. SHA-1). The hash value are reported in the manifest. Then an extra file is added (an `*.SF` file) in the `META-INF/` directory; that file contains entries for each of the signed files: each entry contains the hash of the corresponding entry in the manifest (so it is, more or less, a hash of hash). The `*.SF` also contains an entry containing the hash of the main headers in the manifest. Finally, the `*.SF` file is itself signed, resulting in an `*.RSA` or `*.DSA` file (itself in the `META-INF/` directory) which follows the [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) format (previously known as "PKCS#7"). CMS relies on the whole paraphernalia of X.509 certificates.

So this is rather indirect. What must be understood is that only individual files in the JAR are signed; there can be a mixture of signed and unsigned parts in a given JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is yes:
"Developers can digitally sign JAR files. In that case, the signature information becomes part of the manifest file." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29)